# How to move HANDLE to another HANDLE in winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi

Consider such opening of driver file:

```
HANDLE h = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\" DRIVER_NAME_DOS),
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                0,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                NULL);
```

My question is, if driver is specified to be Exclusive device (which means can be opened only by one entity at the time), how to pass "ownership" from one handle to another?

I don't want to first `CloseHandle(h)` and then `h1=createfile(...)` but to do somthing similar to (its my pseudocode, hope its understandable)

```
h1 = std::move(h)
//h1 has handle to driver file, h is freed
```

Comment: I'm not seeing what is wrong with `h1 = h; h = NULL;` In what way does that not do what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is useful in your particular case, but the function [`DuplicateHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle) may offer you greater flexibility in dealing with ownership of handles.

Comment: Ownership semantics need to be implemented in higher-level library code. An example would be `wil::unique_handle` (see [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/wil/wiki/RAII-resource-wrappers)).

Answer (score 3):

`HANDLE` [is just a pointer under the hood](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types):

```
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
typedef void *PVOID;
```

You can simply assign it to another pointer of the same type:

```
HANDLE h1 = h;
```

As a matter of good coding practice, you better nullify the previous one:

```
h = nullptr;
```

Comment: In this case, it would probably be better to write `h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;`, because OP is dealing with `CreateFile`. You may want to read this for further information about when to use `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and when to use `NULL` (or `nullptr`): [Why are HANDLE return values so inconsistent?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040302-00/?p=40443)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel or use wrapper function for fix `CreateFileW` return value : `HANDLE fixH(HANDLE hFile)
{
 return hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ? 0 : hFile;
}` and use `if (HANDLE hFile = fixH(CreateFileW(..))) { ... }`